# From restricted root space to root space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am reading Knapp's book "Lie Groups beyond Introduction" https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4757-2453-0. I do not understand the following argument in Page 377 (2nd edition). I write the details. Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak g.$ Let $\theta$ be a Cartan involution of $\mathfrak g.$ Let $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak k\oplus \mathfrak p$ be the Cartan decomposition. One can check that because of the inner product induced by $\theta$ we must have that $\{\text{ad}H:H\in\mathfrak a\}$ where $\mathfrak a\subseteq \mathfrak g$ a maximal abelian subspace, is a commuting family of self-adjoint operators. Therefore, we have an eigenspace decomposition of $\mathfrak g$ as $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak g_0\oplus{\oplus}_{\lambda\in\Sigma}\mathfrak g_\lambda,$ which is called a restricted root space decomposition. Moreover, one can proe that $\mathfrak g_0=\mathfrak a\oplus Z_{\mathfrak k}(\mathfrak a).$ One can prove that if $\mathfrak t\subseteq Z_{\mathfrak k}(\mathfrak a)$ is maximal abelian, then $\mathfrak h:\mathfrak a\oplus \mathfrak t$ is a Cartan subalgebra of $\mathfrak g.$ Therefore, we have a rot space decomposition as $(\mathfrak g)^\mathbb{C}=(\mathfrak h)^{\mathbb C}\oplus\oplus_{\alpha\in\Delta}\mathfrak g_\alpha.$ Now one can get back the components of restricted root space decomposition as the following. We have $\mathfrak g_\lambda=\mathfrak g\cap \oplus_{\alpha|_{\mathfrak a}=\lambda}\mathfrak g_\alpha$. I understand clearly upto this. But how to show that $(Z_{\mathfrak k}(\mathfrak a))^\mathbb C=\mathfrak t^\mathbb C\oplus\oplus_{\alpha|_{\mathfrak a}=0}\mathfrak g_\alpha$. However, I can see that $\mathfrak t^\mathbb C\oplus\oplus_{\alpha|_{\mathfrak a}=0}\mathfrak g_\alpha$ commutes with $\mathfrak a^\mathbb C.$